# How to resolve this there is nothing visible in android studio after loading project?

Tags: android-studio

[Help me to reslolve as there is no option for execution and nothing is visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K92uG.png)

Comment: oncreate? Setcontentview?

Comment: Actually this is not my splash activity so it doesn't contain any onCreateView as this is the file in which i am storing my images which is coming from server so simply i just wanna know that why android studio has gone blank!! means no running logo is visible?